# Why are so many Python files really big (5k+ lines)?

Tags: python, coding-style

Is there any specific reason driving Python files to often be so large? Python files may contain several classes within one file, and some files go up over 10k lines in length. This seems to go against the idea of modularity and encapsulation.

Also it doesn't seem "Pythonic" in the first place, considering IMO it can be harder to read and follow.

Comment: This is a question that appears to be primarily opinion based, which is off topic for Programmers.SE

Comment: This is difficult to answer without context. What are you comparing these files to?

Comment: Are these huge files parts of common libraries or something like that? Or just within the project you have at work?

Comment: What make you think that source files should be small ? I often have source files of several thousands of lines.

Comment: 1k+ lines is small, not big.

Comment: Well, it seems odd (coming from a JS/Java/Bash background) to have a single source file that is several thousand lines long. It also doesn't seem to me like it would be "Pythonic", either.

Comment: @GregHewgill Looking at several Python libraries' source code (including the standard library), it is extremely common to see files with upwards of 5k lines, even on occasion upwards of 10. Most other languages I've coded in are usually at their longest less than 3k (I rarely see a JS file or even a C header file longer than 2k lines of code).

Comment: I updated the question (with a change in title to better emphasize the question itself).

Comment: Do you have examples of these very large .py files or an interpretation why it wouldn't be pythonic?

Comment: In the standard library: [`pydoc`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed291f85434b/Lib/pydoc.py) (2615 lines), [/Lib/email/_header_value_parser.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed291f85434b/Lib/email/_header_value_parser.py) (2947 lines), and (third-party) [`httplib2`'s test module (httplib2/python3/httplib2test.py)](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/blob/master/python3/httplib2test.py) (1625 lines)